# Locate div's in a specific order

Tags: html, css

if I have:

```
<div>A</div>
<div>B</div>
<div>C</div>
```

is there a way for the div's to appear this way when the page loads?

```
C
A
B
```

it doesnt matter the method

Comment: Why do you need this requirement?  You'd either have to manipulate the DOM, or move the contents of the `<div>`s around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use display:flex and order to rearrange how the divs look on the dom

check this snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div:nth-child(1) {
  order: 2;
}
div:nth-child(2) {
  order: 3;
}
div:nth-child(3) {
  order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

you can use **css3 flex-box** concept to achieve this

give **display:flex** for the parent container and give **order** property to the child element

```css
#one{
  background-color:red;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  order:2;
  }
#two{
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  order:3;
  }
#three{
  background-color:orange;
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  order:1;
  }

#parent{
  display: flex;
  }
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="one">A</div>
<div id="two">B</div>
<div id="three">C</div>
</div>
```

Comment: why are the order values 15 and 20?

Comment: @sreekanth which is just assigned  to assign in order(it can be 2,3)

Comment: no prob...it's  happened when i try to post the answer fast